# Selec2 dropdown isnt show all items in Response response

Tags: jquery-select2, wicket

I have problem with select 2. It dont show all Items, but only subset. I dont see on Select2Choice any method, which show all items. Can someone give me a poit how to show whole items.

Here is code:

```
originStationDropDown = new Select2Choice<>("originDgfStation", new PropertyModel<Station>(this, "originStation") , new StationsProvider(originCountryDD, productDD));
        ComponentHelper.addLabelAndComponent(originStationDropDown, this, "originStation.label", ComponentOptions.REQUIRED);

 private class StationsProvider extends ChoiceProvider<Station> {

        private Select2Choice<Country> countryDD;
        private DropDownChoice<Product> productDD;

        public StationsProvider(Select2Choice<Country> countryDD, DropDownChoice<Product> productDD) {
            this.countryDD = countryDD;
            this.productDD = productDD;
        }

        @Override
        public void query(String codeNameFragment, int i, Response<Station> response) {
            if(codeNameFragment == null || "".equals(codeNameFragment)) {
                List<Station> stations = stationDao.findByCountryAndProduct(countryDD.getModel().getObject(), productDD.getModel().getObject(), "code");
                for(Station station : stations) {
                    response.add(station);
                }
            } else {
                response.addAll(stationDao.findByCountryAndProductAndFragment(countryDD.getModel().getObject(), productDD.getModel().getObject(), codeNameFragment));
            }
            System.out.println(response.size());
        }

        @Override
        public void toJson(Station station, JSONWriter jsonWriter) throws JSONException {
            jsonWriter.key("id").value(station.getId()).key("text").value(station.getNameWithCode());
        }

        @Override
        public Collection<Station> toChoices(Collection<String> collection) {
            List<Station> stations = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Station> stationList = stationDao.findAll();

            for(String id : collection) {
                for(Station station : stationList) {
                    if(station.getId().equals(Long.valueOf(id))) {
                        stations.add(station);
                    }
                }
            }
            return stations;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't explain which items are shown and which are not.

I will guess that only the first N items are always shown. The second parameter of `#query()` method is `int page` (named `i` in your code). This parameter should be used to paginate the results. I.e. you should not always return 10000 items and let the JavaScript to deal with them but you have to return 0-20, 21-40, 41-60, etc.